# CS50 error: called object type 'int' is not a function or function point in C

Tags: c, if-statement, compiler-errors, cs50, logical-operators

I'm a newbie at programming and currently I'm taking the CS50 course at Harvard edX. I'm trying to solve the "credit" problem but no matter what I keep myself stuck in this **error: called object type 'int' is not a function or point.**

I've already tried to read book fragments, answers on this website and nothing makes sense cause, to me (a newbie, I admit), my int is declared a function!! Can someone help me to see the light on this problem? I'll copy and paste **my code** here below:

```
int lenght_card = 0;
long visa_start = card;
long amex_start = card;
long master_start = card;

while (card > 0)
{
    card = card/10;
    lenght_card++;

}
```

// Identifying the card as Visa

```
{

visa_start = card/10000000000000;

}

if ((visa_start == 4)(lenght_card == 16 || lenght_card == 13));

{
    printf("%s\n," "VISA");
    return 0;
```

*PS:* the error shows up in the line 86 specifically: (lenght_card == 16 || lenght_card == 13));

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: What is `card`? You never defined that variable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello everyone, I've already solve my problem by changing some details in my code.

First, I declared lenght as a function called 'lenght_card' and after that I saw I was forgetting to add '(' to && and || to complete my loop so that was causing unnecessary errors. Plus, because the C reads the code from left to right, I should put the order of 'lenght' before the numeric start of the card. So that solve my code problem and the program started running.

Answer (score -1):

There are typos.

For example in this if statement

```
if ((visa_start == 4)(lenght_card == 16 || lenght_card == 13));
```

you need to remove the semicolon at the end of the statement and seems you missed the logical AND operator

```
if ((visa_start == 4) && (lenght_card == 16 || lenght_card == 13))
```

Another typo is in this call

```
printf("%s\n," "VISA");
```

The comma shall be outside the format string

```
printf("%s\n", "VISA");
```

You could just write

```
puts( "VISA" );
```

Comment: Hey Vlad, thanks a lot! I really didn't saw the typos but now I fixed them. I'm having trouble to see where I should place the || (or) and && (and) syntaxes on my code. Could you or anyone help me?

Comment: @CarolinaCalixto It depends on the logic. I showed in my answer how the condition in the if statement can look..